# Why does this media query not work for my iPhone?

Tags: ios, css, iphone

I used iPhone 6 and 4 to check if another stylesheet is being applied. It did not. Here are my stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 800px)" href="mobileindex.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1100px)" href="desktopindex.css">
```

Yes, there is a gap in them. That space is reserved for tablets later on. For some reason, the mobileindex.css wasn't applied with those settings. I have to switch orientation twice for it to appear. This, however, fixes the problem:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 1000px)" href="mobileindex.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 1100px)" href="desktopindex.css">
```

Is 800px not enough for an iPhone 4 and 6? How come it works now? The page where this happened is msolonko.net.

Comment: Have you tried using `max-device-width` and `min-device-width`? According to [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/), that's the way to go for the iPhone.

Comment: @MarkLanger That worked. When I used just width, it worked until yesterday and then I started not seeing my stylesheets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you please add the media queries below your main style and after that check your Web Application in your Mobile device.

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px) {
   /*Your Mobile Style will be here.*/
}
```

*The main thing is that you are applying the wrong **min-width** and **max-width** for iPhone6 device. The real size of the iPhone6 for responsive design is below.*

**iPhone 6 Portrait**

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) { 
    /*Your Mobile Style will be here.*/
}
```

**iPhone 6 landscape**

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) { 
    /*Your Mobile Style will be here.*/
}
```

Comment: Using max-device-width: 800px and it works. I can now even make it smaller than 800. Do I have to include orientation?

Comment: Yes, Its very help full for Responsive media queries. Please go ahead with orientation.

Comment: So you recommend that I make a separate stylesheet for every different device rather than having general guidelines?

Comment: No, You have to make just one style-sheet like `mediaqueries.css`.

and add media queries for separate device width.